# Android: Canvas gives garbage when shifting a Bitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap, image-manipulation

I would like to use Canvas to "shift a bitmap"; to create a Bitmap from a Bitmap, but with a y offset such that all the pixels in the Bitmap are either shifted down (with blank pixels at the top) or shifted up (with blank pixels at the bottom).  I am using the below code to do this.  The code works fine as long as I am shifting up (shiftY is negative), but it gives a garbage bitmap if I try to shift down.

The second set of code is my work around for this, but this has the very undesirable effect of doubling my memory usage.

Is there any way to shift a Bitmap whitout using a second Bitmap?

```
//create canvas from the current Bitmap.
Canvas canvas = new Canvas (m_Bitmap);
/*draw into the current Bitmap into the canvas with an offset, thereby drawing over itself 
shifted pixels*/
canvas.drawBitmap(m_Bitmap, 0, shiftY, null);
```

`

```
//create the canvas from a temp bitmap
Canvas canvas = new Canvas (m_2ndBitmap);
//draw the shifted pixels into the temp bitmap
canvas.drawBitmap(m_BackBuffer, shiftX, shiftY, null);

//swap the bitmaps  
Bitmap temp = m_Bitmap;
m_Bitmap = m_2ndBitmap;
m_2ndBitmap = temp;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it yourself if you copy row by row from the bottom.  The problem is that your source and destination are the same and it's copying from the top, destroying the rows beneath before you can copy them lower.

Comment: manually reading and writing the pixel data has very significant performance impact; I was hoping for a direction safe way to use Canvas, which performs much better (presumably because it does this stuff natively, etc).  This seemed likely to exist because in java, Graphics2D.drawImage(BufferedImage...) is direction safe.

Comment: You can do blocks of shiftY size -- you will still use drawBitmap, so ultimately it will be height/shiftY drawBitmap calls -- might not be so bad.

Comment: Hmm, the way I was doing this was using Bitmap.getPixels(...) to retrieve all the pixels in the image.  and then drawing the first (height - shiftY) rows of pixels. (for shifting 'up', where shiftY is positive).  I'm not sure what you mean by blocks of shiftY size, is there a better way?

Comment: I am suggesting to loop over the image from the bottom, grab shiftY rows of pixels, then draw them shiftY pixels lower.  Then subtract shiftY from the row, grab the next shiftY pixels and draw them.  When you get to the top of the image, stop.  It will need about height/shiftY iterations of getPixels()/draw to finish.  When shiftY is 1, it needs to loop through each row.  If shiftY is height/2, it only needs two iterations.

Answer (score 0):

When you are referencing a "new" or *new* `Bitmap` to an already existing `Bitmap`, the already existing `Bitmap` will be available for garbage collection.

However, **do not create objects during runtime**: just use two `Bitmap`s that you are allocating up front, when your `Canvas` has been created and skip creating the new `Canvas`.

Comment: I am confused by your answer.  As shown in my question, I understand how to solve this using two Bitmaps.  However, two Bitmaps requires twice the memory and it seems that one Bitmap should suffice, if the draw command didn't fail surprisingly for positive shiftY values. Hence, my inquiry as to if there is an option to use just one bitmap.

Comment: @ab11: Well, if you are trying to use two `Bitmap`s in one application you have to allocate both of them up front. Since you are creating a new `Canvas` from your temporary `Bitmap` that will decrease the performance of your application if that `Canvas canvas = new Canvas(...)` happens during runtime.

Comment: I have no desire to use 2 Bitmaps.  I only want to use 1 Bitmap, which I would like to be able to shift up and down.  However, I find myself using 2 Bitmaps to implement the shifting.

Comment: @ab11: You are creating a new `Canvas` everytime you want to shift `Bitmap`s. If this occurs during runtime the allocating part will take time and the `Canvas` you're using for this is going to be garbage collected. This is your problem.

Comment: how can I shift my Bitmap without creating a new Canavs?

Comment: @ab11: You can't do that during runtime without affecting the performance of your application. Instead you should allocate two `Bitmap`s when your application starts and keep reusing them as long as your application is alive.

Comment: Ok, I think we are mis-communicating here.  My goal is to shift the Bitmap at runtime, the Bitmap will shift in response user input.

Comment: @ab11: Then you are on your way, but your performance will be affected and there is a very logical reason why your memory usage is twice as much.

Comment: well, considering that in Java Graphics2D.drawImage(BufferedImage...) can be used to shift a BufferedImage up or down on to itself without allocating a second image; I was hopeful that there would be a way to do this in android

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap.createBitmap(m_BackBuffer), shiftX, shiftY, null);
```

instead of:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(m_BackBuffer, shiftX, shiftY, null);
```